# NotSupportedException Could not activate JNI Handle - MvvmCross

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I recently updated MvvmCross from 3.5.1 to 4.1.4 in my project and published the app update along with it.

After that, I see from Xamarin Insights that, a lot of users experience;

`Could not activate JNI Handle 0xffb35af8 (key_handle 0xe888654) of Java type 'md53997af0c1a24144057e197743f9f827a/HomeView' as managed type 'package.name.HomeView'` on almost all of the activities with their respective activity names. All these activities are MvxActivities.

My Setup.cs -

```
public class Setup : MvxAndroidSetup
{
    public Setup(Context applicationContext)
        : base(applicationContext)
    {
    }

    protected override IMvxApplication CreateApp()
    {
        return new MVVM.App();
    }

    protected override IMvxTrace CreateDebugTrace()
    {
        return new MvxDebugTrace();
    }

    protected override MvvmCross.Droid.Views.IMvxAndroidViewPresenter CreateViewPresenter()
    {
        var presenter = new MyViewPresenter();

        Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IMvxViewPresenter>(presenter);

        return presenter;
    }

    protected override void FillTargetFactories(MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.Target.Construction.IMvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry registry)
    {
        registry.RegisterCustomBindingFactory<View>(
                 "ShowMe",
                 v => new ViewScalingCustomBinding(v));
        registry.RegisterCustomBindingFactory<View>(
                 "ScaleMe",
                 v => new ViewSizingCustomBinding(v));
        registry.RegisterCustomBindingFactory<View>(
                 "CustomFont",
                 v => new FontCustomBinding(v));
        registry.RegisterCustomBindingFactory<View>(
                 "OtherCustomFont",
                 v => new FontDincCustomBinding(v));
        registry.RegisterCustomBindingFactory<View>(
                 "ImageResize",
                 v => new ImageResizeCustomBinding(v));
        base.FillTargetFactories(registry);
    }

    protected override IMvxPluginConfiguration GetPluginConfiguration(Type plugin)
    {
        if (plugin == typeof(MvvmCross.Plugins.DownloadCache.Droid.Plugin))
        {
            return new MvvmCross.Plugins.DownloadCache.Droid.MvxDownloadCacheConfiguration()
            {
                CacheName = "Pictures.MvvmCross",
                CacheFolderPath = "../Library/Caches/Pictures.MvvmCross/",
                MaxFiles = 500,
                MaxFileAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
                MaxInMemoryBytes = 4000000, // 4 MB
                MaxInMemoryFiles = 1,
                MaxConcurrentDownloads = 10,
                DisposeOnRemoveFromCache = false
            };
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

What could be causing this issue?

Comment: Can you maybe show one of those Activites? And maybe your Setup.cs? Quite a few things have changed with 4, so maybe there is something wrong with the activity headers or so.

Comment: Aside from namespaces and namespace related things, I haven't changed anything in Setup.cs, but I can add it to the question. Activity headers also don't have anything specific except a label and screen orientation.

Comment: And it appears only with some users, you yourself dont have this issue?

Comment: Exactly, I see a lot of users experience it, but I don't, during debugging, and neither our QA team.

Comment: Maybe related to the android version? Do you have any information about that from the affected devices? Not sure if things like MvxAppCompatActivity instead of MvxActivity would make a difference.

Comment: I have the android version info, but it is varied so I don't think it affects a specific version. It seems to be affecting all versions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113399/discussion-between-cyriac-and-can-canbek).

Answer (score 3):

I had that exception without using any custom view. Just try to clean the project, it solved my issue, however still that kind of thing scares me from using Xamarin.